# do something if between 2 dates inside a switch

Tags: php, date, switch-statement

I'm using a switch to change things on a curtain day which is working fine:

```
$today = date('d/m');

switch ($today)
{
case '11/01':
  // do this
  break;
case '15/02':
  // do that
  break;
default:
  // do nothing
}
```

but want to make some of the changes last for more then just 1 day, how can I add a case between date 1 and date 2?

I know I could add many cases to 1 change ie:

```
case '11/01':
case '12/01':
case '13/01':
case '14/01':
case '15/01':
  // do this
  break;
```

but is there a better way as changes can be upto 2 weeks?

Comment: It might be better to use if statements in that case

Comment: My preference is to use switch as there will be a quite few conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use comparison by timestamps. Somehow like this:

```
switch (true) {
case $today == '11/01':
    // do this
    break;
case $today == '15/02':
    // do that
    break;
case ($t = strtotime('today')) >= mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 11) && $t <= mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 15):
    // do smth else
    break;
default:
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: This seems to work `case ($t = date('d/m')) > '01/01' && $t < '14/01':`

Comment: @Anna Riekic No. This can't work properly. This is the same as `$t > 1 && $t < 14`

Comment: It seems to: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd3bf7dc2178dadf2a49a0b5af944f97ccb2e1e8

Comment: @Anna Riekic It SEEMS to work, however it is wrong algo. It works only for dates within one month. But it doesn't work for arbitrary dates like these: `11/3` and `1/4`. Below is proof.
Your wrong algo: http://ideone.com/QU2UE5.
Proper algo: http://ideone.com/Gm3xaU

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple cases but not using break before your last statement like this.

```
switch ($today)
{
case '11/01':
  // do this
  break;
case 'Your other case1':
case 'Your other case2':
case '15/02':
  // will do that for above 3 cases
  break;
default:
  // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Was just adding this as you where posting, but changes can be for aslong as 2 weeks which is alot of code, is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know. Don't think so.